# can't load .po file in functions.php

Tags: php, functions

I get this warning

> Notice: Undefined variable: pofiles in
> /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php on line 237
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php on line 237

when I am trying to load po file with function, like this

```
foreach ($pofiles as $pofile) {
    $domain = baseName($pofile, 'http://localhost:8100/var/www/html/wp-content/languages/ponamefile.po');
    $lang = baseName(dirName(dirName($pofile)));
    /*
    # build .mo file for gettext
    #
    echo "Building $lang $domain.mo ...\n";
    $mofile = preg_replace('/\.po$/', '.mo', $pofile);
    passThru( 'msgfmt -o '. qsa($mofile) .' '. qsa($pofile), $err );
    if ($err !== 0) {
        echo "  Failed.";
        if ($err === 127) echo " (msgfmt not found. gettext not installed?)";
        echo "\n";
    }
    */
    # build .php file for php
    #
    echo "Building {$lang} {$domain}.php ...\n";
    $phpout = _po_to_php($pofile);
    if (!is_array($phpout)) {
        $phpout = array();
    }
    $phpout = '<' . "?php\n" . "// AUTO-GENERATED FILE. TO MAKE CHANGES EDIT\n" . "// " . $domain . ".po AND REBUILD\n\n" . $copyright . "\n\n" . '$g_gs_LANG[\'' . $lang . '\'][\'' . $domain . '\'] = ' . var_export($phpout, true) . ";\n\n" . '?' . '>';
    $phpfile = preg_replace('/\\.po$/', '.php', $pofile);
    $f = fOpen($phpfile, 'wb');
    fWrite($f, $phpout, strLen($phpout));
    fClose($f);

}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, `$pofiles` isn't defined anywhere. What is it supposed to be? Where is this code? What is the code for? You shouldn't need to do anything like this in a normal theme.

Comment: @JacobPeattie $pofiles shoud be a directory with diffrent po files for wordpress translation. I will add this code. I agree with you regarding theme, but this i will need to translate wordpress admin panel from cyrilic to latin charachters. I agree with you that this shoudnt be done this way, but this is request so i have to make it works.